# angular 2 parent and child component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

- I am trying to learn typescript and angular2.
- so I tried to include  parent and child components in my fiddle.
- but I am not successful. even did some research
- I am geting this error 
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/t9ef4cdt/

```or-tag-here
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <button (click) = "rename()" > Rename Parent </button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {

@Input() name:string;
@Output() nameChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using deprecated angular version (as it is appearing from your imports), You can find your code working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jntsuc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I think jsFiddle is not uptodated about angular versions , I saw it now it supports angular2 on its alpha version (very old and deprecated version), you can use stackblitz instead , https://stackblitz.com/.

Comment: I understood using this line you are making a new text to get reflected...can you give me some more explanation so that in future I will do it by myself...    this.nameChanged.emit('Renamed');

Comment: Once clicking on `rename()` here `<button (click) = "rename()" > Rename Parent </button>` you're firing a function that emits an event (send a 'renamed' string) from child to parent component, in the parent component you're affecting that string to a parameter `name` which in its turn will be updated on the Html by the newer value (the sent string).

Comment: hey I used your stackblitz and included my ui from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fdnoz2ka/...when I click open first button window its not working...any idea https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fn9khc

Comment: You are using jQuery , (not recommanded with angular, if you need it add it to the dependencies) also you're using some features of Kendo ui within jQuery which is an other issue, + you should not add your html codes in index.html, why just you do not start here https://angular.io/guide/quickstart :)

Comment: hey can you update in the link...its hard to fix it :(